# Automatic bash script interaction

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been trying to make a bash script that interacts with a program.

I need to run "script1" (the program, ie. "./script1.sh"), and i need "script2" (bash script) to be run and read the questions, and respond with answers, back to "script1".

It's the actual interaction between the two script i cannot solve.

Restrictions:

- Use of `expect` or other similar functions is not allowed, it must be run on linux shell commands.
- script1.sh will launch several randomly generated questions in concession. Each must be answered right.

I have tried using an array of techniques:

- `/proc/[pid]/fd/0` (for using stdin, but it seems constricted to terminal and not the shell process itself)
- Using netcat to setup a pipe (This works but leaves me back at square one with regards to the interaction: Reading and replying)
- Using pipes (`./script1.sh | the_pipe`, but this doesn't allow any input to be given back to "script1")
- Using normal files for input (`./script1.sh < answer.txt > question.txt`, but it seems that `answer.txt` is only read once on script start-up?)
- Using named pipes (`./script1.sh < answer.pipe > question.pipe`, but the script stalls on start because of the answer.pipe blocks it. If i force a carriage return to the answer.pipe to get the process started, "script1" fails, as the carriage return is a wrong answer)
- I have tried using background processes to break down the different tasks (ie. `./script_to_parse_questions.sh &`, then saving the result to a file, which is read once and then deleted etc.)

I think "the linux way" might probably be to use pipes "|" or brackets "<>", but it's probably just me who cannot get it working properly.

(Edited for clarification)

Comment: expect is the linux way of doing interaction between a script and any program.  Anything else that does interaction would count as a "similar technique" so I'm not sure what you are allowed or not.

Comment: Are the answers always the same?

Comment: @glennjackman no, the answers are randomly generated each session.

Comment: Are you allowed to change both scripts or only one of them?

Comment: @kaylum i can only change “script2.sh”, - not the primary program. (Script1)

Answer (score 3):

This is where you would want to use a bash [Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses) (introduced in bash v4.0 -- [NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS#n937))

Suppose we have a file that contains the questions and answers:

```
$ cat q_and_a 
Q1
answer one
this is question two
ans 2
question the third
I say thrice
```

Then "script1" can read this file, ask the questions in random order, and know what the correct answer is:

```
$ cat script1.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read the q_and_a file
qs=()
as=()
while read -r q; read -r a; do
    qs+=( "$q" )
    as+=( "$a" )
done < q_and_a

# ask the questions in random order
readarray -t order < <(
    printf "%d\n" "${!qs[@]}" | shuf
)

for i in "${order[@]}"; do
    echo "${qs[i]}"
    read -r ans
    if [[ $ans == "${as[i]}" ]]; then
        echo "answer to '${qs[i]}' is CORRECT"
    else
        echo "answer to '${qs[i]}' is WRONG"
    fi
done
```

Now, "script2" can invoke script1 as a *coprocess*, listen for a question, provide the answer, and then listen for the response to the answer:

```
$ cat script2.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read the q_and_a file
declare -A qa
while read -r q; read -r a; do
    qa[$q]=$a
done < q_and_a

coproc ./script1.sh

for ((i=0; i < ${#qa[@]}; i++)); do
    read -r question <& ${COPROC[0]}
    echo "script1 asked: '$question'"

    echo "answering: '${qa[$question]}'"
    echo "${qa[$question]}" >& ${COPROC[1]}

    read -r response <& ${COPROC[0]}
    echo "script1 responded: '$response'"
done
```

Running script2 might look like:

```
$ ./script2.sh
script1 asked: 'this is question two'
answering: 'ans 2'
script1 responded: 'answer to 'this is question two' is CORRECT'
script1 asked: 'question the third'
answering: 'I say thrice'
script1 responded: 'answer to 'question the third' is CORRECT'
script1 asked: 'Q1'
answering: 'answer one'
script1 responded: 'answer to 'Q1' is CORRECT'
```

Probably in your case, you may not have a shared file with the questions and answers, but you since script2 has the question, you can do what you need to do to analyze it and provide the appropriate answer.

Comment: "script1.sh" must be started, and then "script2.sh" must be able to interpret the readout and reply to this. "script1.sh" will feed several randomly generated questions in concession. I'm sorry if this was not clarified properly.

Comment: Updated my answer